# How to format dates when using libreoffice?

Tags: libreoffice

I'm using following command to convert xlsx to csv, which works :

```
libreoffice --convert-to csv:"Text - txt - csv (StarCalc)":44,34,UTF8,1,,0,false,true,false,false,false,-1 date.xlsx
```

Two questions :

1. If the date inside xlsx is input with `31/12/2022`, then I have correct format in csv as `2022/12/31`, but if the date inside xlsx is input with `31/Dec/2022`, no conversion is made. Is there any option of libreoffice to convert all formats to `2022/12/31` ?
2. Above command produces csv for all the sheets in xlsx, is there a way to select sheets we want ?

Comment: Is there really `31/Dev/2022` with a "V"? Did Calc accept that as a date in the GUI?

Comment: @thebusybee Well spoted. It's a typo, it's `Dec`.